# how to find length of a Long Column in a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, ora-00905

I have a LONG column named FileSize in a table called Files.

To achieve the objective, I did the following :

I wrote this PL/SQL script to find the size

```
declare 
long_var LONG:=0;
begin
dbms_output.put_line(length(long_var));
  execute immediate 'SELECT FILESIZE INTO long_var FROM FILES';
    dbms_output.put_line(length(long_var));
end;
```

But it throws an error :

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

I was doing the following as I saw thw following on the link given below: 
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/long_length.php

Can some one suggest what I am doing wrong as I can not identify the key word I am missing

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in this context.

```
DECLARE 
long_var long:=0;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LENGTH(long_var));
  SELECT filesize INTO long_var FROM files;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LENGTH(long_var));
END;
/
```

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE runs a stand alone statement of SQL from your PL/SQL code.  It can't return anything to your code.  The statement you're using isn't valid SQL so you get the ORA-00905.  It is valid PL/SQL code and so works as you'd expect once  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is removed.

**Edit**

Code for your follow on question: To do this with more than one row you can use this

```
DECLARE 
  CURSOR C1 IS
  SELECT filesize FROM files;
BEGIN
  FOR files IN c1
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LENGTH(files.filesize));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Now I get this error :

ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 5

Comment: Your SELECT expects only one row but you have many, so you need to filter it with a WHERE clause to get only one.  If you want to get the length of many rows you will need to use a cursor instead.  Alternatively you can make this into a function and then use that in a normal select statement.

Comment: It had been a while since I used DBMS_OUTPUT package.. remember to do "set serveroutput on" - also: unfortunately this method fails when LONG column data exceeds 32k (at least for my 32-bit SQL*Plus client). To detect length for larger LONG values I had to use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497238/get-the-length-of-a-long-raw