# Get the LENGTH of a LONG RAW

Tags: oracle, ora-00932, ora-00997

I have a table with a column of data type `LONG RAW`. How do I determine the size (in bytes) of the data in this column?

If I call the `LENGTH` function on it, it raises `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got LONG BINARY`.

Just in case you think it: `UTL_RAW.LENGTH` raises `ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype` :)

(Yes, I know `LONG RAW` is deprecated - the question came up due to some old software that might require it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to manipulate LONG RAWs longer than 32k in PLSQL. Here is a java procedure that returns the length of a LONG RAW.

First, the setup:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE my_table (ID NUMBER, my_long_raw_column LONG RAW);

Table created

SQL> INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('123456789'));

1 row inserted
```

The java class (my java is a bit rusty):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Raw" AS
  2  import java.io.*;
  3  import java.sql.*;
  4  import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
  5  
  6  public class Raw {
  7  
  8     public static int getLength(int pk) throws SQLException,IOException {
  9  
 10        Connection conn = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
 11  
 12        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement
 13           ( "SELECT my_long_raw_column FROM my_table WHERE id = ?" );
 14        ps.setInt( 1, pk);
 15        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
 16  
 17        int len = 0;
 18        if (rs.next()) {
 19           InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
 20           int nb = is.read(new byte[1024]);
 21           while (nb>0) {
 22              len += nb;
 23              nb = is.read(new byte[1024]);
 24           }
 25        } else
 26           len = -1;
 27  
 28        rs.close();
 29        ps.close();
 30
 31        return len;
 32     }
 33  }
 34  /

Java created
```

Let's call it:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  FUNCTION get_lr_length(p_id NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
  3  AS LANGUAGE JAVA
  4  NAME 'Raw.getLength(int) return int';
  5  /

Function created

SQL> select get_lr_length(id) from my_table;

GET_LR_LENGTH(ID)
-----------------
                9
```

I've tested the function with larger than 32k fields and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the data in the column does not exceed 16,383 bytes, you can solve this with a PL/SQL function, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_lr_length (id IN NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER IS
  raw_data LONG RAW;
  hex_data VARCHAR2(32767);
  len      NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT my_long_raw_column INTO raw_data
  FROM my_table
  WHERE my_table.id = get_lr_length.id;
  hex_data := RAWTOHEX(raw_data);
  len := LENGTH(hex_data) / 2;
  RETURN len;
END get_lr_length;
```

Unfortunately, a LONG RAW can hold up to 2GB...

Comment: You can use utl_raw.length on a PLSQL LONG RAW variable directly (since LONG RAW is synonym with RAW (32767) in PLSQL if I remember correctly). Consequently, you can measure a RAW up to 32767 bytes :)

Comment: Also from [this thread on Asktom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:201012348073), it seems that manipulating LONG RAW longer than 32k in PLSQL is not possible. You may need to write a java function to get the length of your raw.

Comment: @Vincent: do you not get `ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype`? That's what I get when I call utl_raw.length on a LONG RAW (Oracle 11.2.0.1.0)

Comment: not in PLSQL (since LONG RAW gets translated to RAW(32767)): this is my function `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_lr_length (p_id IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS raw_data LONG RAW; BEGIN SELECT my_long_raw_column INTO raw_data FROM my_table WHERE my_table.id = p_id; RETURN utl_raw.length(raw_data); END;`

Comment: +1 Vincent - if you supplied that as an answer I'd give it another +1 - it's better than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

One dirty trick, which might help if you're playing with a small test database: copy all data in a table with a `BLOB` instead of a `LONG RAW`.

```
create table START(ID int not null, VAL long raw);
... inserts
create table START_BLOB(ID int not null, VAL blob);
insert into START_BLOB(ID,VAL) select ID,to_lob(VAL) from STAR;
select ID,length(VAL) from START_BLOB;
```