# Oracle - How do I get the actual size of a specific ROW?

Tags: oracle, size, row

Is this possible? Or at least I'm looking to have a list of the size of all rows in a table.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
select vsize(col1) + vsize(col2) + vsize(col3) + 
long_raw_length_function(long_col) + DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(blob_col) 
from table 
where id_col = id_val;
```

for the *long_raw_length_function*, see this [Get the LENGTH of a LONG RAW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497238/get-the-length-of-a-long-raw)

Comment: is `herp/derp` replacing `foo/bar` for arbitrary examples in code?

Comment: `herp/derp` is significantly more derogatory, so I think not.

Comment: Thank you but what if one of the columns is a Long Raw?

Comment: replace vsize with [UTL_RAW.LENGTH(derpy_long_col);](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/A96197_01/ap_urpkg.htm)

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

Comment: My bad. Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497238/get-the-length-of-a-long-raw/5497260#5497260

Comment: LONG and LONG RAW have been deprecated for more than fifteen years now, precisely because they are a pain to work with.

Comment: Note that `VSIZE` returns size of a specific value, not of the column on disk. It returns different sizes for different values of the same column.

Answer (score 10):

if you're interested in the average row length, you could analyze the table (with the DBMS_STATS package), then query `ALL_TABLES.avg_row_len`.

Comment: It may return lower value than sum of column lengths in bytes. Does it reflect actual disk storage space taken by an average row?

Comment: @olexa: It seems the `avg_row_len` column takes into account the [actual space occupied by data](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1041629603947).  In most cases, it should be larger than the average of the sum of the size of the individual columns since there is small overhead at the column level (for instance: NULL values take space when not at the end of a row). Of course if you're using compression it could be lower.

Answer (score 3):

Here below is the query I have modified to get the table row length when you don't have any data. This can help you with Capacity planning for Environment setup:

```
SET serveroutput ON linesize 300
DECLARE
  v_max_size       NUMBER := 0;
  v_owner          VARCHAR2(30);
  v_table_name     VARCHAR2(30);
  v_data_type      VARCHAR2(30);
  v_data_length    NUMBER := 0;
  v_data_precision NUMBER := 0;
  CURSOR CUR_TABLE
  IS
    SELECT DISTINCT table_name
    FROM all_tab_columns
    WHERE owner='TMS_OWNER'
    AND table_name NOT LIKE 'VIEW%'
    ORDER BY table_name;
BEGIN
  FOR Tab IN CUR_TABLE
  LOOP
    v_table_name := Tab.table_name;
    v_max_size   := 0;
    FOR i        IN
    (SELECT owner,
      table_name,
      data_type,
      data_length,
      data_precision
    FROM all_tab_columns
    WHERE owner    ='TMS_OWNER'
    AND table_name = v_table_name
    )
    LOOP
      IF i.data_type = 'NUMBER' THEN
        v_max_size  := (v_max_size + i.data_precision);
      ELSE
        v_max_size := (v_max_size + i.data_length);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line(chr(10));
    dbms_output.put_line('Table ='||v_table_name||', Max Record Size = '||v_max_size||' bytes');
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question of the topic, because the physical size of a specific row is requested. This script will only show the theoretical logical max size based on dictionary, but not the resulting max physical size of a specific row.