# Oracle Sql - How to get data size from outputted query result?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Trying to determine how much data size my application is writing to the Oracle database each week. My application writes to multiple tables.

I know how to query the inserted rows that my application inserted for a week and the result returns thousands of records but how do I determine how much data/filesystem size my application is eating up in the db?

```
select distinct app.id, table1.*, table2.*  FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.purchase_order=table2.purchase_order join table1.id=app.id
where table1.order_date between trunc(sysdate - 7) and trunc(sysdate) - 1/86400;
```

Comment: Check this thread --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871369/oracle-how-do-i-get-the-actual-size-of-a-specific-row

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle - How do I get the actual size of a specific ROW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871369/oracle-how-do-i-get-the-actual-size-of-a-specific-row)