# Copying data from LOB Column to Long Raw Column

Tags: oracle, blob, long-integer

I was looking for a query which picks data from a table having Blob column and update a table having LONG RAW column. It seems Oracle supports only up to 4000 characters. Is there a way to copy full data from blob to long raw.

I was using the follwing query

```
insert into APPDBA.QA_SOFTWARE_DUMMY 
     select SOFTWARE_ID, UPDATED_BY, CREATE_CHANGE_DATE, FILE_NAME,
            DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(SOFTWARE_FILE, 4000) SOFTWARE_FILE, SOFTWARE_TYPE 
       from APPDBA.QA_SOFTWARE_DUMMY_TEST ;
```

but DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR supports only upto 4000 characters.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: [`LONG RAW`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i4146) columns support up to 2GB of data. And why are you going from `LOB` to `LONG RAW` when you should be going the other way around?

Comment: I need this as the DB I am using is pretty old and we have to use this unless and untill the LONG RAW is convertrd to LOB.

Answer (score 4):

PL/SQL will only read/write the first 32k of a LONG RAW and SQL will convert the column as a RAW so will only deal with the first 2000 bytes.

You can use java to access LONG RAW columns directly from the DB, as demonstrated in the question ["Get the LENGTH of a LONG RAW"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497238/get-the-length-of-a-long-raw).

Here's a little example, first the setup:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t (ID NUMBER PRIMARY key, source BLOB, destination LONG RAW);

Table created

SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_lob BLOB;
  3  BEGIN
  4     INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'FF', '') RETURNING SOURCE INTO l_lob;
  5     FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
  6        dbms_lob.writeappend(l_lob, 4000,
  7                             utl_raw.overlay('FF', 'FF', 1, 4000, 'FF'));
  8     END LOOP;
  9  END;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

The java class:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Raw" AS
  2  import java.io.*;
  3  import java.sql.*;
  4  import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
  5  
  6  public class Raw {
  7  
  8     public static void updateRaw(int pk) throws SQLException,IOException {
  9  
 10        Connection conn = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
 11  
 12        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement
 13           ( "SELECT dbms_lob.getlength(source) length, source "
 14           + "FROM t WHERE id = ? FOR UPDATE");
 15        ps.setInt( 1, pk);
 16        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
 17  
 18        rs.next();
 19        int len = rs.getInt(1);
 20        InputStream source = rs.getBinaryStream(2);
 21        byte[] destArray = new byte[len];
 22        int byteRead = source.read(destArray);
 23        ps = conn.prepareStatement(
 24           "UPDATE t SET destination = ? WHERE id = ?");
 25        ((OraclePreparedStatement) ps).setRAW(1,
 26                                             new oracle.sql.RAW(destArray));
 27        ps.setInt(2, pk);
 28        ps.execute();
 29     }
 30  }
 31  /

Java created
```

You can call this procedure from PL/SQL:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PROCEDURE update_raw(p_id NUMBER)
  3  AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Raw.updateRaw(int)';
  4  /

Procedure created

SQL> exec update_raw(1);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that you make a reversal (normaly you should move from LONG to LOB, LONG being obsolete)...

You must use dbms_lob package, and make some plsql:

Eventualy you can use read, getlength...

Doc you can find here [Psoug.org](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_lob.html)
or on [Oracle doc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm)