# Copy data from table with LONG RAW column from one database to another database

Tags: oracle

I need to create JOB in Pentaho Kettle to automate copying data from one database to another database. I am facing problem while copying data from table containing a long raw column.
I have tried below listed things:

1. I have used copy table wizard.But getting error "ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column" while copy for table containg LONG RAW column.Tables in both databases are exactly same.
2. I have tried creating a oracle function to use pl/sql to insert long raw data by binding the long raw column.
   I am making call to oracle function in "Execute sql script" step in PENTAHO.
   select function_name(prameter1,parameter2,long raw column,.....) from dual.
   But getting error "String literal too long".

Any suggestion how to do copy long raw data having size around 89330 bytes from one table to another.

Answer (score 0):

Tom Kyte writes:

> August 26, 2008 - 7pm UTC:
>
> long raw, not going to happen over a database link

(https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1101164500346436784)

You can try to create "temporary" table at one source DB where you convert from `LONG RAW` to `CLOB` using function `TO_LOB`.
And then you can transfer data to destination DB.

Then, if you absolutely need `LONG RAW` data type, you can convert back using method described here - [Copying data from LOB Column to Long Raw Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266092/copying-data-from-lob-column-to-long-raw-column)