# select length of oracle long raw with sql statement

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, size, arrays

storing filedata via a hibernate (using postgresql or oracle 10g/11g) property mapped as

```
        <property name="fileData" type="binary">
            <column name="fileData" length="104857600" />
        </property>
```

from a java application i need to access the length of the field from the db (i do not want to load whole the object, for performance reasons). i did not find any hibernate (hql) solution to query that information, so i decided to search for features of the different databases that were used. for postgresql i found:

```
select BIT_LENGTH(filedata) from table
```

which works perfectly (and astonishing fast). now i need something similar for the use with oracle. i already tried

```
select utl_raw.length(filedata) from table
```

and
    select DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(filedata) from table

which both results in the error msg:

"Error: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype"

is there any possibilty to query the length of that hibernate property on an oracle db without selecting the object itself?

(hibernate creates a "long raw" field on oracle, and a "bytea" field on postgresql)

thx in advance

(addition: statement will be used in a migration-context, newly created filedata entities will get a filesize property programatically)

Comment: `104857600` length's field - it is very powerful

Comment: content length of the field is dynamic, 104857600 is just the upper bound for that field

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the LENGTH of a LONG RAW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497238/get-the-length-of-a-long-raw)

Comment: it's possible i just don't get it (i'm do not have much oracle knowledge), but "SELECT my_long_raw_column FROM my_table WHERE id = ?" from the mentioned answer will load the complete long raw / bytearray which is what i want to prevent my code from. pl/sql is not an option for me also, at least afaik

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like i found an answer here: 
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2137593

```
create table temp_deleteme as select to_lob(<long raw field>) obj from <tablename>;
select dbms_lob.getlength(obj) from temp_deleteme;
```

after creating the tempTable i can select the filedatalength from it, write it to my entities, and delete the table again. still not really good performance, but that let the db do the work and i will not have to transfer entities to my server for only calculating the needed information.

Comment: you can use a database function to avoid using temp table https://community.oracle.com/thread/657507