# Get size of LONG RAW data column in ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle. I want to get size of binary data store in LONG RAW column, I execute this query

```
SELECT LENGTH(BINARY_DATA) FROM MY_DATATABLE WHERE ID = 58;
```

But I get error

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got LONG BINARY
```

What wrong with my Query?
Thanks.

Comment: **Do not use LONG datatype. Oracle advised to migrate to LOBs a long time ago**

Comment: I working for a system create in 2001 , can not migrate because can not change the data structure ^^!

Comment: LOB were introduced in Oracle 8i released in 1998.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a good solution for this problem. You can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497238/get-the-length-of-a-long-raw) and see if this helps, but *it's time to upgrade.*

Comment: You **can** change the data structure; you (or someone else) has chosen not to.

Answer (score 0):

> The LENGTHB function is supported for single-byte LOBs only. It cannot be used with CLOB and NCLOB data in a multibyte character set.

LENGTH() expects `CHAR` as it's parameter.

[image]

**Documentation:**[LENGTH](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions088.htm#SQLRF00658)

Comment: Any solution for my data type LONG RAW ?